# Endless pending, when uploading an image file

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, redux, axios

I want to upload articles to my database, which are including image- and video files. I get no error, but the pending status is endless.

Here is a snippet, where I overgive the data (The console.log in the fileChange function shows the right image file):

```
const [formdata, setFormdata] = useState(
    {
      ressort:"",
      theme:"",
      title:"",
      content:"",
    }
  )
  const {ressort,theme,title,content} = formdata;
  const [fileData, setFileData] = useState({
    img:""
  })
  const {img} = fileData;
  const fileInput = useRef(img);
  const fileChange = (e)=>{
    console.log(fileInput.current.files);
    setFileData(fileInput.current.files[0])
  }
  console.log(fileData); //works
  const handleChange = (e)=>{
    setFormdata((prevState)=>({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }))
  }
  const onSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("img", fileData);
    console.log(data);
    const mainnewsData ={
      data,
      ressort,
      theme,
      title,
      content
    }
    console.log(mainnewsData);
    dispatch(createMainNews(mainnewsData));
  }
```

Here is my createMainNews out of my slice:

```
export const createMainNews = createAsyncThunk("mainNews/create", async (mainnewsData, thunkAPI)=>{
    try{
        const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
        return await mainnewsService.createMainNews(mainnewsData, token);
    } catch(error){
        const message = (error.response && 
            error.response.data && 
            error.response.data.message)
            || error.message
            || error.toString()
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
})
```

Here is my service:

```
const API_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/mainNews/";
const createMainNews = async (mainnewsData, token)=>{
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            "token": `Bearer ${token}`
          },
    }
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, mainnewsData, config);
    return response.data;
}
```

And finally my backend(upload is the multer storage):

```
router.post("/", verifyTokenAndAuthorization,upload.single("img"), async (req,res)=>{
    const newMainNews = new MainNews({
        img: req.file.originalname,
        ressort: req.body.ressort,
        theme: req.body.theme,
        title: req.body.title,
        content:req.body.content,
    });
    try{
        const savedMainNews = await newMainNews.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedMainNews);
    } catch(error){
        res.status(403)
        throw new Error("Aktion fehlgeschlagen");
    }
});
```

Comment: Check if the router handler for `POST /` is actually being called. If not, the issue might be in `verifyTokenAndAuthorization` (or `upload.single()`, but I doubt that).

Comment: I modified my service file. The post handler is called. Now I have an error. It throws the error out of my backend and tells me: "Cannot set headers after they are send to the client."

Comment: I have fixed the error by changing my backend. The upload must be set before the verifyTokenAndAuthorization.